# How to make Wikipedia forward to article instead of going to search

Tags: google-chrome, browser, wikipedia

I recently updated to Win10, using chrome as always I found that Wikipedia doesn't forward to an article anymore when I type in correct word but forwards to search results instead.

It also doesn't do auto-complete when writing in query box, it ought to be linked.

What happened? It's so annoying and I want old behavior back.

This also happens in MS Edge.

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? (Press Ctrl+Shift+J if you don't know how to open the console.) Also, do you have a Wikipedia account?